# How to handle webview using appium and selenium with java

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am doing testing on Amazon android app for learning purpose. I have done few basic test cases and executes it successfully. Now i want to login but I don't know how to handle webview in appium and selenium with java. Please help me.

Comment: I cant see any question... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This code is just for switching from native app context to webview context,

get all context in this case webView and native app

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();

for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextNames); 
}
driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[1]);

//switch to inapp webview, and do Your stuff, if webview is enabled for automation

String myText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("buttonId")).click();

driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

//switch back to app
```

and here is a link how to locate and list elements in webView, here is a nice article how to connect to webView via Chrome on remote device (Android)

[https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3]

So You could check elements and if it enabled for automation testing.

Answer (score 0):

To switch to webView in your android app, **webView debugging** should be enabled in your app. For Amazon android app webView is not enabled. You can refer this [link](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-identify-webview-elements-in-android-hybrid-app/5140)

You can develop your own android app by enabling remote debugging webView or you can use chrome browser which comes with webView enabled.

To switch to WebView :

```
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
    for(String context : contextNames) {
        if(context.contains("WEBVIEW")){
            System.out.println("Context Name is " + context);
            driver.context(context);                
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I have enable debugging mode of my app. Can you please share whole code snippet with me. I need it.